# Implementing Rich Text Environment with Clickable Mathematical Structures

Tags: python, tkinter, latex, sympy

I am trying to create a rich text environment that incorporates clickable mathematical structures.

I aim to develop a user-friendly platform that allows users to seamlessly interact with mathematical notations, such as roots or fractions, within a rich text environment. The primary functionalities I am trying to implement include:

Clickable Mathematical Structures: Users should be able to click on specific mathematical structures, such as fractions or radicals, within the text environment.

Dynamic Addition: Upon clicking these structures, they should be added to the rich text environment without disrupting the flow of the text. Users should be able to write or insert additional content within these mathematical structures.

Nested Structures: The system should support nested mathematical structures, allowing users to add new writing or mathematical elements within the existing structures.

This would then need to be converted to LaTeX markup, which can then be converted to sympy readable code.

How should I approach this?

Currently I am having the user input LaTeX markup which is continuously compiled and displayed using matplotlib and PIL.

Some prompts:

1. \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2}
2. \frac{d}{dx}\tan(x)
3. \int\frac{1}{1+\sin(x)}dx
   etc.

Here is the current code for my sympy GUI so you can get the jist of what I'm trying to do (please pardon the fact that it's long):

```
import tkinter as tk
import gc
from sympy import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tempfile
import os
import latex2sympy2 as l2s

# Create a tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("LaTeX in Tkinter")

entry = tk.Entry(window, width=60)
entry.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)

# Create initial figures and axes for "Update" and "Calculate" buttons
fig_update, ax_update = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))
fig_calculate, ax_calculate = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))

def update():
    
    try:
        latex_expr = r'${}$'.format(entry.get())

        # Clear the old content and create a new figure
        try:
            ax_update.clear()
            plt.close(fig)
            gc.collect()
        except:
            pass
        fig, ax_update = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))
        ax_update.text(0.5, 0.5, latex_expr, size=12, ha='center', va='center', usetex=True)
        ax_update.axis('off')

        # Save the figure as a temporary image
        temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        temp_image_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, "expression.png")
        fig.savefig(temp_image_file, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, transparent=True)

        # Open and display the temporary image using tkinter
        image = Image.open(temp_image_file)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        label = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
        label.image = photo
        label.grid(row=0, columnspan=5)

        window.after(1000, update)
        try:
            ax_update.clear()
            plt.close(fig)
            gc.collect()
        except:
            pass
    except:
        try:
            ax_update.clear()
            plt.close(fig)
            gc.collect()
        except:
            pass
        window.after(1000, update)
update()

def calculate():
    latex_expr = r'${}$'.format(entry.get())
    try:
        ax_calculate.clear()
        plt.close(fig_calculate)
        gc.collect()
    except:
        pass
    if '==' in latex_expr:
        pos_equals = latex_expr.find('==')
        latex_expr_left = latex_expr[:pos_equals]
        latex_expr_right = latex_expr[pos_equals+2:]

        sympy_expr_left = l2s.latex2sympy(latex_expr_left)
        sympy_expr_right = l2s.latex2sympy(latex_expr_right)

        if simplify(sympy_expr_left) == simplify(sympy_expr_right):
            latex_expr = 'True'
        else:
            latex_expr = 'False'
        # Create a new figure and axes for the "Calculate" button
        fig_calculate, ax_calculate = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))
        ax_calculate.text(0.5, 0.5, latex_expr, size=12, ha='center', va='center', usetex=True)
        ax_calculate.axis('off')

        # Save the figure as a temporary image
        temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        temp_image_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, "expression.png")
        fig_calculate.savefig(temp_image_file, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, transparent=True)

        # Open and display the temporary image using tkinter
        image = Image.open(temp_image_file)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        label = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
        label.image = photo
        label.grid(row=1, columnspan=5)
    else:
        latex_expr = r'${}$'.format(entry.get())
        latex_expr += '='
        latex_expr += r'${}$'.format(latex(l2s.latex2sympy(entry.get()).doit()))
        # Create a new figure and axes for the "Calculate" button
        fig_calculate, ax_calculate = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))
        ax_calculate.text(0.5, 0.5, latex_expr, size=12, ha='center', va='center', usetex=True)
        ax_calculate.axis('off')

        # Save the figure as a temporary image
        temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        temp_image_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, "expression.png")
        fig_calculate.savefig(temp_image_file, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, transparent=True)

        # Open and display the temporary image using tkinter
        image = Image.open(temp_image_file)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        label = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
        label.image = photo
        label.grid(row=1, columnspan=5)
    try:
        ax_calculate.clear()
        plt.close(fig_calculate)
        gc.collect()
    except:
        pass
    



calculate = tk.Button(window,width=12,height=4,text="calculate",command=calculate)
calculate.grid(row=3, column=0)

# Run the tkinter main loop

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: *How should I approach this* is a suitable question for a tutor, not for stackoverflow. Here you do ask *That's my approach and it doesn't work, even though it should, depending on the research I did.* You might ask this question on SuperUsers

Comment: Sorry @Thingamabobs, I didn't know this wasnt that kind of forum